# Jquery display text from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, text, show

Maybe someone can give me a little help.
I modified a jquery to appear as i wanted, you can see it here: http://loja.genesiseries.com/depoimentos/index.html

But i need display text from mysql DB, so i created a new page and put php echo.
http://loja.genesiseries.com/depoimentos/mysql.php

It work, but not as i wanted.
**What i need**: When the visitor click in proximo (NEXT) button the jquery show the next div with a new text from database
**What is happening**: When i click in proximo (NEXT) button the jquery shows the next div but don't load a new text, how to fix it?

I was wondering now and maybe is a good improvement remove the previous button (anterior) since the button will load a random text, doesn't make sense back to it, or do? i'm also thinking about the div limit, here i just put 3 DIVS, **when I get it at the end of divs the jquery shows first div again, how to fix it**?

I know absolutely nothing about jquery.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM opinions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
$depoimento = $linha["depoimento"];
$client = $linha["client"];

}
?>
```

Now the divs

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">

        <div>
            <p class="depoimento"><font color="#bdbdbd"><?php echo "$depoimento"; ?></font></p><p class="cliente"><font color="#99CB1E"><?php echo "$client"; ?></font></p>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <p class="depoimento"><font color="#bdbdbd"><?php echo "$depoimento"; ?></font></p><p class="cliente"><font color="#99CB1E"><?php echo "$client"; ?></font></p>
        </div>

   <div>
<p><font color="#bdbdbd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed                 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</font>    </p>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your PHP is setting variables from the database, but not printing them to the page.

Comment: Yes, they are! <p class="depoimento"><font color="#bdbdbd"><?php echo "$depoimento"; ?></font></p><p class="cliente"><font color="#99CB1E"><?php echo "$client"; ?></font></p>

Comment: But that's not inside the `while` loop that reads from the database, so it just prints the variables from the last iteration.

Comment: santanu kumar already give me the code, but can you give me a example please? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this .`Grab` all the content inside `$silder_content` and show inside html

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM opinions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
$silder_content="";
while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
$depoimento = $linha["depoimento"];
$client = $linha["client"];

$silder_content .='<div>
            <p class="depoimento"><font color="#bdbdbd">'.$depoimento.'</font></p><p class="cliente"><font color="#99CB1E">'.$client.'</font></p>
        </div>';

}
?>

<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container"> 

    <?php echo $silder_content; ?>

   <div>
<p><font color="#bdbdbd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed                 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</font>    </p>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check it: loja.genesiseries.com/mysql2.php 
But this way will load ALL from DB correct? Does this will make the page more slowly?

Comment: no it depends on how many records you want to show..but if you have large data then you should try for json data

Comment: Well, there will be 100+ records :\ This json will be more light?

Comment: Because that way EVERYONE would be harmed, would be cool to just load one by one when clicked. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @user2415711 One by one also will be slow as you have to access each time the database but if you hold the data during initial page load then you can manipulate throughout the page .

Comment: Ah, ok
Just one more thing, you can give me a example of json manipulation or something to read? so i can learn

Thanks bro!

Comment: you can check this for json tutorial http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with this code, they are reassigning the same variables as they go through the loop and they aren't echoing anything.

Try something like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT `depoimento`, `client` FROM opinions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
$ret = array();
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
while ($linha=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $ret[] = $linha;
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Hello Orangepill, thanks for you answer but with your code this appear: [{"depoimento":"Test Depoiment #1","client":"Client #1"},{"depoimento":"Test Depoiment #2","client":"Client #2"}]

I am using the code in the wrong way, used exactly as you put
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the DIVs inside the `while` loop:

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container"> 
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM opinions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
    $silder_content="";
    while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {

        $depoimento = $linha["depoimento"];
        $client = $linha["client"];

        echo '<div>
                <p class="depoimento"><font color="#bdbdbd">'.$depoimento.'</font></p><p class="cliente"><font color="#99CB1E">'.$client.'</font></p>
              </div>';

    }
    ?>

     <div>
       <p><font color="#bdbdbd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed                 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</font>    </p>
     </div>

   </div>
</div>
```